# Swift 3 - How to assign delegate for UIScrollView on .xib file?

Tags: swift, file, uiscrollview, delegates, xib

I'm trying to add the zoom and pinch images function into my application. I had found a lots of useful ways to do that on the internet.

The ways that I found are at main storyboard, to assign delegate to UIScrollVIew, right click on UIScrollView and drag it to the ViewController on the storyboard and click on Delegate, and it is done.

BUT, I'm not using the main storyboard for some reason, I'm using the .xib file, and that solution could not apply to my situation. So, is there anyone know how to assign delegate for UIScrollView on a .xib file?

Comment: What kind of class is the .xib file? A view? Is the UIScrollView a subview of the .xib file? Show current code for where the xib is used(what view controller it is used on) and what code is currently in the xib class.

Answer (score 0):

Control drag from `UIScrollView` to `File's Owner` and choose `delegate` in the popup black window.[image]

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there anyone know how to assign delegate for UIScrollView on a .xib file?

Why not do it in code?

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myScrollView.delegate = self
}
```